# proof of $x(t)=1$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $x(t)>0$, $\int_0^1x(t)dt=1$ and $\int_0^1\ln x(t)dt=0$, can we prove that $x(t)=1$ almost everywhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "almost everywhere"? The question seems very interesting.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: "almost everywhere" means (for the sake of this conversation) 1 in every point except perhaps countable number of points. (So for instance, it is 1 except for the values 1/2, 1/4, 1/8,...)

Comment: Okay.Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Use Jensen's inequality. The $\ln$ function is strictly concave, so you get equality a.e. as desired.

Comment: @kimchilover Could you write the details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $x>0$ we have $\ln(x)-x+1\ge0$, with equality only if $x=1$. Hence,  $g(t) = \ln x(t) -x(t)+1$ is non-negative for $t\in[0,1]$.  But we can evaluate its integral:
$$ \int_0^1 g(t)\,dt = \int_0^1 \ln x(t)\, dt - \int_0^1 x(t)\,dt + 1 = 0.$$
Since $g$ is non-negative, and has zero integral, it must itself be zero almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, that is, $\ln x(t) -x(t)+1=0$ a.e.  But this forces $x(t)=1$ a.e.